# How to bring data from model to controller to use in session using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am sorry. Weak in english. Neglect Grammatical Errors.
As i searched, i got to knew that session is being handled by controller. I'm not getting in which part i've to use session. How to bring data from model to controller to declare it session based values.

Controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('news_model');
    $this->load->library('session');

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    }
public function check_login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('EmpID', 'Employee ID', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('EmpPassword', 'Employee Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
        else
        {
        $loginCredentials=$this->news_model->login_credentials();
        if($loginCredentials==='Member')
        {   
            redirect('/welcome/member_CAttachments'); //redirecting to member folder
        }

        }
}
```

Model

```
public function login_credentials()
    {
        $empID=$this->input->post('EmpID');

        $this->db->where('EmployeeID',$this->input->post('EmpID'));
        $this->db->where('Password',md5($this->input->post('EmpPassword')));
        $query=$this->db->get('member');

        if($query->num_rows()==1)
        {
            $this->db->where('EmployeeID=', $empID);
            $queryMemberType = $this->db->get('member');
            foreach ($queryMemberType->result() as $row)
            {
                $MemberType=$row->MemberType;
            }
            if($MemberType=='Admin')
            {
                return 'Admin';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what i mean to say. That, OK. I can store email/employee Number using POST in session. But, What about that auto-incremented employee Id, which is in MODEL. Please help me. I'm new to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the data from model you just need to add that data to session object like this : 
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');

And If you want to see session added data. you can use :
$this->session->userdata('come_name
');

Answer (score 1):

in model if your condition `if($query->num_rows()==1) { .... }` is true then you need to set login employee data in session then you can access login employee information anywhere you can access in controller and also in view ...so please set session...it will work..